# Clone one MicroSD card to another

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

So, I have a Raspbian Lite booted from [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn), the bootloader, on my Raspberry Pi 2B v1.1. I have it all written on a 8.0GB micro SD Card. I just bought an upgrade - a 64.0GB micro SD. I have **a lot** of things on my original 8GB SD, so I don't want to have to manually re-install every little thing I have.

My question is this: Is there a way to clone my whole card, with every partition, using the terminal in Raspbian Lite to a new SD Card?

I have tried [rpi-clone](https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone): it seems to only copy over two partitions.

I have the 64GB plugged in via a USB adapter, no problem there.

Here are my partitions on my 8.0GB card:

[image: The partitions on my 8.0GB Card]

Thanks, Bobbay

Comment: what about dd?) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix) ))

Comment: I was hoping to clone off of the host device itself, but @marksetchell - 's answer was pretty good, so I'll take that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to duplicate your SD card on a computer where the operating system is not running from that SD card - mainly because the contents of the card could change while you are duplicating it in a live system.

So, I would boot a PC off a live distro, like [Knoppix](https://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html). Once booted, start a Terminal and check the names of the disk drives like this:

```
ls /dev/sd?
```

You'll probably just have `/dev/sda`, but check! Now attach your 8GB SD card, wait a couple of seconds and check what name that got allocated. It's likely to be `/dev/sdb`

```
ls /dev/sd?
```

If it's `/dev/sdb` save that as SRC (source), like this:

```
SRC=/dev/sdb
```

Now attach your 64GB SD card, wait a couple of seconds and check what name that got allocated. It's likely to be `/dev/sdc`

```
ls /dev/sd?
```

If it's `/dev/sdc` save that as DST (destination), like this:

```
DST=/dev/sdc
```

**If, and only if, everything works as above**, you can now clone `SRC` to `DST` with:

```
sudo dd if=$SRC of=$DST bs=65536
```

The command above will take a fair time to run. Once it is complete, you will have a clone of your original disk, as `/dev/sdc` However, this will have the same size partitions as your 8GB drive, so you will want to expand the partitions out to fill the available space. I don't know which one(s) you want to expand, or by how much, but you will want to use the `resize2fs` command on the new disk. You can get help on that with:

```
man resize2fs
```

Comment: Copying rw mounted running system can make broken duplicate so I would suggest to do it on PC in an off-line mode. Adding example command-line for extending last partition with resize2fs would help OP as well

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny Yes, that is good advice. Thank you. I will update my answer.